# Installation issue EnrichmentMap Pipeline Collection

Tags: installation, failed-installation, cytoscape, installation-package

I've installe Cytoscape 3.10 on a MAcbook Pro 2020 with Ventura. I can't install the collection, but I do not have any particular error message. It can't start the Java application and said just to check the console for possible error message. Any suggestion?

Thank you

I've tried to download the entire collection and also the single package, but in both ways I can't properly install the apps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to download anything.  To install the enrichment map collection, you should start Cytoscape and then go to the App Store, find the Enrichment Map collection, and then click "Install".  Each of the packages should install in your running Cytoscape.